# Disable ARRAffinity cause session issue

Tags: azure, kentico, azureportal, azure-redis-cache

I have a website which is developed using Kentico 10 and hosted on Azure.
It has Azure Application gateway, scaled out to 2 instances and webfarms are also enabled. Its using Azure Redis cache as well

Today I disabled ARRAffinity in the app service (via Azure Portal) and kept Cookies based affinity enabled in the application gateway.

Still, I can see the app is consuming the Redis cache however when I add an item to shopping cart and then click on the view cart it shows the empty shopping cart (randomly) where our shopping cart is stored in a session.
So I believe this is something related to sticky session issue even with the Redis cache.

1. Since I've disabled the ARRAffinity in the app service does is it required to disable the Cookies based affinity from the app gateway-> https settings?
2. If not, anything I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an App Service and scaling out to 2 instances the Application gateway does not provide load balancing capabilities.

The load balancing is being handled by the app service.  If you wanting to control that a traffic manager profile might help.

So you would still need to leave ARR on in the app service.

Comment: Is there any way that we can secure ARRAffinity cookie in azure ?

Comment: What is the goal?  Not sure if you have saw this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/securing-the-arraffinity-cookie/ba-p/342598